# Is there an ERM diagram for the Sylius Framework?

Tags: symfony, orm, entity-relationship, sylius

I am new to [Sylius](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/model.html). For [Shopware](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/entity-relationship-model/) there is an ERM diagram. Does anything likewise exist for Sylius?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen one yet, but you can easily generate it from existing database with for example MySQL Workbench and Reverse Engineering option.